# If $(f_n)_n$ and $(g_n)_n$ converge stochastically to $f$ and $g$, then $(f_n+g_n)_n$ converges stochastically to $f+g$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space
- $(E,d)$ be a separable metric space
- $f,g,f_n,g_n:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to(E,\mathcal{B}(E))$ measurable
- $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq E$

We say that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **converges stochastically** to $f$ $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\left\{d(f,f_n)>\varepsilon\right\}\cap A\right)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }\varepsilon>0\;\text{and }A\in\mathcal{A}\;\text{with }\mu(A)<\infty\tag{1}$$ Let's denote this by $f_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}f$.

---

Under which further restrictions (if any) to the involved objects do the following statements hold:

1. $f_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}f$ and $g_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}g$ $\Rightarrow$ $$f_n+g_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}f+g$$
2. $f_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}f$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a\in E$ $\Rightarrow$ $$a_nf_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}af$$

---

<sub>*Please note*: We define $$\left\{\operatorname{cond}(f)\right\}:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega :\operatorname{cond}\left(f(\omega)\right)\right\}$$ where $\operatorname{cond}\left(f(\omega)\right)$ is any condition $f(\omega)$ may satisfy.</sub>

Comment: I've provided an answer which makes some further restrictions. I would be happy if someone could vote my answer and/or could prove the statements with lesser restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first take a look on $(1.)$. I claim that $(1.)$ holds if $d$ is subadditive, i.e. $$d(f_n+g_n,f+g)\le d(f_n,f)+d(g_n,g)\tag{2}$$ *Proof*: $(2)$ implies that $$\underbrace{\left\{d(f_n+g_n,f+g)>\varepsilon\right\}}_{=:C_n}\subseteq\underbrace{\left\{d(f,f_n)>\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}}_{=:A_n}\cup\underbrace{\left\{d(g,g_n)>\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}}_{=:B_n}\;\;\;\text{for all }\varepsilon>0$$ Since $\mu$ is subadditive, we've got $$\mu(C_n\cap A)\le \underbrace{\mu(A_n\cap A)}_{=:\alpha_n}+\underbrace{\mu(B_n\cap A)}_{=:\beta_n}\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal{A}\;\text{with }\mu(A)<\infty$$ But,

- $f_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}f\Rightarrow\alpha_n\to0$
- $g_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}g\Rightarrow\beta_n\to0$

Thus, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(C_n\cap A)=0$$

---

Now, let's take a look on $(2.)$. I claim that $(2.)$ holds if $(E,d)$ is a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $$d(x,y)=\left\|x-y\right\|\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E$$ where $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ is a norm on $E$.

*Proof*:

- Let $$s:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\|a_n\right\|<\infty$$
- Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$
- Choose $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\mu\left(\left\|f\right\|>\frac{\varepsilon K}2\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}2$$
- $f_n\stackrel{\text{stoch}}{\to}f$ and $a_n\to a$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $$\mu\left(\left\{s\left\|f-f_n\right\|>\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}\cap A\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}2\tag{3}$$ and $$\left|a_n-a\right|\le\frac{1}{K}\tag{4}$$ for all $n\ge N$
- Since $$\left\|af\color{blue}{-a_nf+a_nf}-a_nf_n\right\|\le|a-a_n|\cdot\left\|f\right\|+|a_n|\cdot\left\|f-f_n\right\|\tag{5}$$ we've got $$\begin{matrix}\mu\left(\underbrace{\left\{\left\|af-a_nf_n\right\|>\varepsilon\right\}}_{=:C_n}\cap A\right)&\stackrel{(5)}{\le}&\mu\left(\left\{|a-a_n|\cdot\left\|f\right\|>\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}\cap A\right)+\mu\left(\left\{|a_n|\cdot\left\|f-f_n\right\|>\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}\cap A\right)\\&\stackrel{(3)\text{ and }(4)}{\le}&\mu\left(\left\{\left\|f\right\|>\frac{\varepsilon K}2\right\}\cap A\right)+\mu\left(\left\{s\cdot\left\|f-f_n\right\|>\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}\cap A\right)\\&\le&\frac{\varepsilon}2+\frac{\varepsilon}2\end{matrix}$$
- Thus, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(C_n\cap A)=0$$